# An SqlParameter with ParameterName '@OE_PurchaseDate' is not contained by this SqlParameterCollection

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

im getting this error when i changed my textbox to datetimepicker

here is my code

```
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = sqlconn.CreateCommand
        sqlconn.Open()
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.CommandText = "AddOfficeEquipmentProfile"
        cmd.Parameters("@OE_PurchaseDate").Value = dtpPurchaseDate.Value
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        sqlconn.close
```

this is my stored procedure as follows

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddOfficeEquipmentProfile
(

@OE_PurchaseDate    smalldatetime,      

)
AS

INSERT INTO tblOfficeEquipmentProfile (OE_PurchaseDate) 
VALUES (@OE_PurchaseDate)
GO
```

Comment: Does your stored procedure `AddOfficeEquipmentProfile` contain a parameter called `OE_PurchaseDate`?

Comment: yes sir please take a look at my stored proc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the error message is quite straightforward. You need to [add the parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wbys3e9s.aspx) before attempting to set its value.

```
cmd.CommandText = "AddOfficeEquipmentProfile"
cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_PurchaseDate",SqlDbType.SmallDateTime)
cmd.Parameters("@OE_PurchaseDate").Value = dtpPurchaseDate.Value
```